# Cant Load Utf8 Columns In Csv

Tags: php, csv, utf-8

I want to upload a csv file with php it havent any problem with english columns but it have problem with utf8 and Persian characters what should i do to solve this problem?i googled about this but everything i did not useful ....

Comment: Is this a file you generate and want to upload it to another server or is this a file that is given to you and want to parse it through your application? Your question is a bit cryptic.

Comment: my friend i write this code before and on my last server its ok but when i change my server it make a problem. i try every function for utf8 and csv but doesnt useful ....... now i want to know what shoudl i do to can support utf 8 for my code like getcsv and ....

Comment: Can you please provide some of the code so that we can see what you are trying to do? It might be something related to the server or your code. Without more information I'm afraid I cannot help much...

Answer (score 0):

Use something: unicode, utf-16 or utf-32